# How to show and hide tab bar at required places?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xib

Hi i am making an application where ther are four screens(view controllers) from 1 to 4. I want to show screen 1 without tab bar .This screen will have three buttons through which user can navigate to other screens. Now when user taps screen 2 button then user should navigate to screen 2 with tab bar on bottom.Now this tab bar will have four tabs from screen 1 to 4 to navigate .Similarly when now user tap on tab 1 then the scrren 1 should arrive which is without tab bar and so on.
      My problem is i am not able to load or unload tab bar at required places.I have tried following:

1. I opened screen 1 on statrt up and on screen 1's view did load added the tab bar but it didnt work
2. I added tab bar on main window but then tab bar starts to show even on screen 1.

   PLease tell me the correct way to do this (In other words a tab bar with four tabs in which the first screen should not show tab bar)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

First add your rootviewcontroller in the window.
and add three buttons in it.

on clicking event of button add tabbarcontroller to mainwindow

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.tCtr.selectedIndex = btntag;  //ur button tag;
delegate.tCtr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:delegate.tCtr animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

use this single line

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

for hide tab bar. use this before push the page where you want tab Bar hidden and also write this line

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=No;
```

at same page from where you are going to push in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: THere is no navigation controller in my app. Just a tab bar with four tabs .From which i dont want to show tab bar on first one

Comment: Then add navigation bar in TabBarItems in MainWindow.

Comment: Tab bar is hidden when application starts